# Haskell pre-monadic I/O

Tags: haskell, io, monads

I wonder how I/O were done in Haskell in the days when IO monad was still not invented. Anyone knows an example.

Edit: Can I/O be done without the IO Monad in modern Haskell? I'd prefer an example that works with modern GHC.

Comment: There is a brief summary of how it used to work in the first part of the paper [Tackling the awkward squad: monadic input/output, concurrency, exceptions, and foreign-language calls in Haskell](https://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/marktoberdorf/) by Simon Peyton Jones, which I highly recommend reading if you're interested in this topic, although most of the paper is about how monadic IO works.

Comment: See chapter 7 of the 1.2 Haskell Report - this was prior to the introduction of monads http://haskell.cs.yale.edu/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/haskell-report-1.2.pdf

Comment: In addition, see @shachaf's great answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536761/what-other-ways-can-state-be-handled-in-a-pure-functional-language-besides-with/13538351#13538351).

Comment: You my find monads conceptually challenging, but monadic IO is significantly less irritating than it was previously, as I remember all too clearly.

Comment: ghc doesn't give you another option. The IO monad is it.

Comment: If you'd like to write I/O the way we did before the `IO` monad, you can get close to it by omitting `do` and using `>>= (\reposonse -> ...` whilst closing as few of these brackets as possible until the end of your program.

Comment: I wrote an [overview](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13538351/712548) for a related SO question.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Before the IO monad was introduced, `main` was a function of type `[Response] -> [Request]`. A `Request` would represent an I/O action like writing to a channel or a file, or reading input, or reading environment variables etc.. A `Response` would be the result of such an action. For example if you performed a `ReadChan` or `ReadFile` request, the corresponding `Response` would be `Str str` where `str` would be a `String` containing the read input. When performing an `AppendChan`, `AppendFile` or `WriteFile` request, the response would simply be `Success`. (Assuming, in all cases, that the given action was actually successful, of course).

So a Haskell program would work by building up a list of `Request` values and reading the corresponding responses from the list given to `main`. For example a program to read a number from the user might look like this (leaving out any error handling for simplicity's sake):

```
main :: [Response] -> [Request]
main responses =
  [
    AppendChan "stdout" "Please enter a Number\n",
    ReadChan "stdin",
    AppendChan "stdout" . show $ enteredNumber * 2
  ]
  where (Str input) = responses !! 1
        firstLine = head . lines $ input
        enteredNumber = read firstLine
```

As Stephen Tetley already pointed out in a comment, a detailed specification of this model is given in chapter 7 of the [1.2 Haskell Report](http://haskell.cs.yale.edu/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/haskell-report-1.2.pdf).

---

> Can I/O be done without the IO Monad in modern Haskell?

No. Haskell no longer supports the `Response`/`Request` way of doing IO directly and the type of `main` is now `IO ()`, so you can't write a Haskell program that doesn't involve `IO` and even if you could, you'd still have no alternative way of doing any I/O.

What you can do, however, is to write a function that takes an old-style main function and turns it into an IO action. You could then write everything using the old style and then only use IO in `main` where you'd simply invoke the conversion function on your real main function. Doing so would almost certainly be more cumbersome than using the `IO` monad (and would confuse the hell out of any modern Haskeller reading your code), so I definitely would not recommend it. However it *is* possible. Such a conversion function could look like this:

```
import System.IO.Unsafe

-- Since the Request and Response types no longer exist, we have to redefine
-- them here ourselves. To support more I/O operations, we'd need to expand
-- these types

data Request =
    ReadChan String
  | AppendChan String String

data Response =
    Success
  | Str String
  deriving Show

-- Execute a request using the IO monad and return the corresponding Response.
executeRequest :: Request -> IO Response
executeRequest (AppendChan "stdout" message) = do
  putStr message
  return Success
executeRequest (AppendChan chan _) =
  error ("Output channel " ++ chan ++ " not supported")
executeRequest (ReadChan "stdin") = do
  input <- getContents
  return $ Str input
executeRequest (ReadChan chan) =
  error ("Input channel " ++ chan ++ " not supported")

-- Take an old style main function and turn it into an IO action
executeOldStyleMain :: ([Response] -> [Request]) -> IO ()
executeOldStyleMain oldStyleMain = do
  -- I'm really sorry for this.
  -- I don't think it is possible to write this function without unsafePerformIO
  let responses = map (unsafePerformIO . executeRequest) . oldStyleMain $ responses
  -- Make sure that all responses are evaluated (so that the I/O actually takes
  -- place) and then return ()
  foldr seq (return ()) responses
```

You could then use this function like this:

```
-- In an old-style Haskell application to double a number, this would be the
-- main function
doubleUserInput :: [Response] -> [Request]
doubleUserInput responses =
  [
    AppendChan "stdout" "Please enter a Number\n",
    ReadChan "stdin",
    AppendChan "stdout" . show $ enteredNumber * 2
  ]
  where (Str input) = responses !! 1
        firstLine = head . lines $ input
        enteredNumber = read firstLine 

main :: IO ()
main = executeOldStyleMain doubleUserInput
```

Comment: You can probably use unsafeInterleaveIO instead of unsafePerformIO.  That would be the lazy-I/O model that old Haskell used to do.  You could probably also give it a modern spin by using io-streams, pipes, or conduit.

Comment: `unsafeInterleaveIO` is definitely the way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd prefer an example that works with modern GHC.

For GHC 8.6.5:

```
import Control.Concurrent.Chan(newChan, getChanContents, writeChan) 
import Control.Monad((<=<))

type Dialogue = [Response] -> [Request]
data Request  = Getq | Putq Char
data Response = Getp Char | Putp

runDialogue :: Dialogue -> IO ()
runDialogue d =
  do ch <- newChan
     l <- getChanContents ch
     mapM_ (writeChan ch <=< respond) (d l)

respond :: Request -> IO Response
respond Getq     = fmap Getp getChar
respond (Putq c) = putChar c >> return Putp
```

where the type declarations are from page 14 of [How to Declare an Imperative](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.91.3579&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Philip Wadler. Test programs are left as an exercise for curious readers :-)

If anyone is wondering:

```
 -- from ghc-8.6.5/libraries/base/Control/Concurrent/Chan.hs, lines 132-139
getChanContents :: Chan a -> IO [a]
getChanContents ch
  = unsafeInterleaveIO (do
        x  <- readChan ch
        xs <- getChanContents ch
        return (x:xs)
    )
```

yes - `unsafeInterleaveIO` does make an appearance.

Answer (score 0):

**@sepp2k** already clarified how this works, but i wanted to add a few words

> I'm really sorry for this. I don't think it is possible to write this function without unsafePerformIO

Of course you can, you should almost never use unsafePerformIO
http://chrisdone.com/posts/haskellers

I'm using slightly different `Request` type constructor, so that it does not take channel version (`stdin` / `stdout` like in **@sepp2k's** code). Here is my solution for this:

(Note: `getFirstReq` doesn't work on empty list, you would have to add a case for that, bu it should be trivial)

```hs
data Request = Readline
             | PutStrLn String

data Response = Success
              | Str String

type Dialog = [Response] -> [Request]


execRequest :: Request -> IO Response
execRequest Readline = getLine >>= \s -> return (Str s)
execRequest (PutStrLn s) = putStrLn s >> return Success


dialogToIOMonad :: Dialog -> IO ()
dialogToIOMonad dialog =
    let getFirstReq :: Dialog -> Request
        getFirstReq dialog = let (req:_) = dialog [] in req

        getTailReqs :: Dialog -> Response -> Dialog
        getTailReqs dialog resp =
            \resps -> let (_:reqs) = dialog (resp:resps) in reqs
    in do
        let req = getFirstReq dialog
        resp <- execRequest req
        dialogToIOMonad (getTailReqs dialog resp)
```

Comment: This looks very wrong to me, since you call `dialog` many times in the implementation of `dialogToIOMonad`. A correct implementation should only call `dialog` once, and it should provide it with a lazy list of responses. I think you can get away with using `unsafeInterleaveIO` instead of `unsafePerformIO`, but you can’t do it in a pure way without duplicating work.

Comment: Using unsafeInterleaveIO would still result in using unsafe* function, which i was trying to avoid by all means. I would love to see implementation with calling dialog only once, tho.