# Monads, composition and the order of computation

Tags: haskell, monads, composition

All the monad articles often state, that monads allow you to sequence effects in order.

But what about simple composition? Ain't

```
f x = x + 1
g x = x * 2

result = f g x
```

requires `g x` to be computed before `f ...`?

Do monads do the same but with handling of effects?

Comment: That's not function composition, which would be `(g . f) x`. Secondly the result of `f x` is not needed, since haskell has call by need aka lazy evaluation. `f` will be applied as late as possible, I.e. when printing `result`. Finally, yes, monads create something like hidden parameters, that represent the state of the world, and chains those parameters between the actions  so that despite the lazy evaluation, the effects will happen in the order that is intended

Comment: It doesn't type-check, either. `f g x` is the same as `(f g) x`, so you would be trying to add 1 to a function.

Comment: C'mon, the OP obv meant `f (g x)`, and yes, it could be that it requires `g x` to be computed "before" `f`, *if* `f` is strict in its argument. But if `f` is lazy, it might not be. Here though, this specific `f` *is* strict, because `+` is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: Monads are a lot of things. They are notoriously difficult to explain, so I will not attempt to explain what monads are *in general* here, since the question does not ask for that. I will assume you have a basic grasp on what the `Monad` interface is as well as how it works for some useful datatypes, like `Maybe`, `Either`, and `IO`.

---

## What is an effect?

Your question begins with a note:

> All the monad articles often state, that monads allow you to sequence effects in order.

Hmm. This is interesting. In fact, it is interesting for a couple reasons, one of which you have identified: it implies that monads let you create some sort of sequencing. That’s true, but it’s only part of the picture: it *also* states that sequencing happens on **effects**.

Here’s the thing, though… what is an “effect”? Is adding two numbers together an effect? Under most definitions, the answer would be no. What about printing something to stdout, is that an effect? In that case, I think most people would agree that the answer is yes. However, consider something more subtle: is short-circuiting a computation by producing `Nothing` an effect?

### Error effects

Let’s take a look at an example. Consider the following code:

```
> do x <- Just 1
     y <- Nothing
     return (x + y)
Nothing
```

The second line of that example “short-circuits” due to the `Monad` instance for `Maybe`. Could that be considered an effect? In some sense, I think so, since it’s non-local, but in another sense, probably not. After all, if the `x <- Just 1` or `y <- Nothing` lines are swapped, the result is still the same, so the ordering doesn’t matter.

However, consider a slightly more complex example that uses `Either` instead of `Maybe`:

```
> do x <- Left "x failed"
     y <- Left "y failed"
     return (x + y)
Left "x failed"
```

Now this is more interesting. If you swap the first two lines now, you get a different result! Still, is this a representation of an “effect” like the ones you allude to in your question? After all, it’s just a bunch of function calls. As you know, `do` notation is just an alternative syntax for a bunch of uses of the `>>=` operator, so we can expand it out:

```
> Left "x failed" >>= \x ->
    Left "y failed" >>= \y ->
      return (x + y)
Left "x failed"
```

We can even replace the `>>=` operator with the `Either`-specific definition to get rid of monads entirely:

```
> case Left "x failed" of
    Right x -> case Left "y failed" of
      Right y -> Right (x + y)
      Left e -> Left e
    Left e -> Left e
Left "x failed"
```

Therefore, it’s clear that monads do impose some sort of sequencing, but this is not because they are monads and monads are magic, it’s just because they happen to enable a style of programming that *looks* more impure than Haskell typically allows.

### Monads and state

But perhaps that is unsatisfying to you. Error handling is not compelling because it is simply short-circuiting, it doesn’t actually have any sequencing in the result! Well, if we reach for some slightly more complex types, we can do that. For example, consider the `Writer` type, which allows a sort of “logging” using the monadic interface:

```
> execWriter $ do
    tell "hello"
    tell " "
    tell "world"
"hello world"
```

This is even more interesting than before, since now the result of each computation in the `do` block is unused, but it still affects the output! This is clearly side-effectful, and order is clearly very important! If we reorder the `tell` expressions, we would get a very different result:

```
> execWriter $ do
    tell " "
    tell "world"
    tell "hello"
" worldhello"
```

But how is this possible? Well, again, we can rewrite it to avoid `do` notation:

```
execWriter (
  tell "hello" >>= \_ ->
    tell " " >>= \_ ->
      tell "world")
```

We could inline the definition of `>>=` again for `Writer`, but it’s too long to be terribly illustrative here. The point is, though, that `Writer` is just a completely ordinary Haskell datatype that doesn’t do any I/O or anything like that, and yet we have used the monadic interface to create something that looks like ordered effects.

We can go even further by creating an interface that looks like *mutable state* using the `State` type:

```
> flip execState 0 $ do
    modify (+ 3)
    modify (* 2)
6
```

Once again, if we reorder the expressions, we get a different result:

```
> flip execState 0 $ do
    modify (* 2)
    modify (+ 3)
3
```

Clearly, monads are a useful tool for creating interfaces that *look* stateful and have a well-defined ordering despite actually just being ordinary function calls.

## Why can monads do this?

What gives monads this power? Well, they’re not magic—they’re just ordinary pure Haskell code. But consider the type signature for `>>=`:

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

Notice how the second argument depends on `a`, and the only way to get an `a` is from the first argument? This means that `>>=` needs to “run” the first argument to produce a value *before* it can apply the second argument. This doesn’t have to do with evaluation order so much as it has to do with actually writing code that will typecheck.

Now, it’s true that Haskell is a lazy language. But Haskell’s laziness doesn’t really matter for any of this because all of this code is actually pure, even the example using `State`! It’s simply a pattern that encodes computations that look sort of stateful in a pure way, but if you actually implemented `State` yourself, you’d find that it just passes around the “current state” in the definition of the `>>=` function. There’s not any actual mutation.

And that’s it. Monads, by virtue of their interface, impose an ordering on how their arguments may be evaluated, and instances of `Monad` exploit that to make stateful-looking interfaces. You don’t *need* `Monad` to have evaluation ordering, though, as you found; obviously in `(1 + 2) * 3` the addition will be evaluated before the multiplication.

## But what about `IO`??

Okay, you got me. Here’s the problem: `IO` is magic.

**Monads are not magic, but `IO` is.** All of the above examples are purely functional, but obviously reading a file or writing to stdout is not pure. So how the heck does `IO` work?

Well, `IO` is implemented by the GHC runtime, and you could not write it yourself. However, in order to make it work nicely with the rest of Haskell, there needs to be a well-defined evaluation order! Otherwise things would get printed out in the wrong order and all sorts of other hell would break loose.

Well, it turns out the `Monad`’s interface is a great way to ensure that evaluation order is predictable, since it works for pure code already. So `IO` leverages the same interface to guarantee the evaluation order is the same, and the runtime actually defines what that evaluation means.

**However, don’t be misled! You don’t need monads to do I/O in a pure language, and you don’t need `IO` to have monadic effects.** [Early versions of Haskell experimented with a non-monadic way to do I/O](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17004448/465378), and the other parts of this answer explain how you can have pure monadic effects. Remember that monads are not special or holy, they’re just a pattern that Haskell programmers have found useful because of its various properties.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the functions you proposed are strict for the standard numerical types. But not all functions are! In

```
f _ = 3
g x = x * 2
result = f (g x)
```

it is *not* the case that `g x` must be computed before `f (g x)`.

Comment: IMO this question is not really about laziness or strict evaluation order but about how the monadic interface allows sequencing of effects and what it provides over ordinary Haskell evaluation (whether it’s lazy or not). See my overly long answer for what I *think* OP was asking, and feel free to correct me if you think I’m wildly off-base.

Comment: @AlexisKing Laziness is absolutely at the heart of the matter: the use of monads became popular in Haskell precisely because, unlike strict languages, lazy languages can leave some things completely unevaluated and therefore if we left "effectful" things in the lazy fragment those effects might never happen at all! Monads turned out to be useful in their own right later; but originally, they were there to _solve a problem_, and my view is that this question is precisely asking why the naive, pure solution to that problem isn't good enough.

Comment: Hmm, that’s fair, even if I don’t agree completely (I think that line of reasoning mostly applies to `IO`, but while `IO` may have been the driving force behind the invention of monads, the history is somewhat irrelevant for new learners). I don’t know the history of the “discovery” of monads, and if you had any literature on their introduction I would be very interested in reading it. IMO, though, I think I disagree with your last sentence: my answer specifically describes why the idea of monadic effects *is* pure aside from `IO`. Only OP can give clarification on the intent, though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, monads use function composition to sequence effects, and are not the only way to achieve sequenced effects.

## Strict semantics and side effects

In most languages, there is sequencing by strict semantics applied first to the function side of an expression, then to each argument in turn, and finally the function is applied to the arguments. So in JS, the function application form,

```
<Code 1>(<Code 2>, <Code 3>)
```

runs *four* pieces of code in a specified order: 1, 2, 3, then it checks that the output of 1 was a function, then it calls the function with those two computed arguments. And it does this because **any** of those steps can have side-effects. You would write,

```
const logVal = (log, val) => {
  console.log(log);
  return val;
};
logVal(1, (a, b) => logVal(4, a+b))(
  logVal(2, 2),
  logVal(3, 3));
```

And that works for those languages. These are *side-effects*, which we can say in this context means that JS's type system doesn't give you any way to know that they are there.

Haskell does have a strict application primitive, but it wanted to be *pure*, which roughly means that it wanted the type system to track effects. So they introduced a form of *metaprogramming* where one of their types is a type-level adjective, “programs which compute a _____”. A program interacts with the real world; Haskell code in theory doesn't. You have to define “`main` is a program which computes a unit type” and then the compiler actually just *builds that program* for you as an executable binary file. By the time that file is *run* Haskell is not really in the picture any more!

This is therefore *more specific* than normal function application, because the abstract problem I wrote in JavaScript is,

1. I have a program which computes {a function from (X, Y) pairs to programs which compute Zs}.
2. I also have a program which computes an X, and a program which computes a Y.
3. I want to put these all together into a program which computes a Z.

That's not *just* function composition itself. But a function **can do** that.

## Peeking inside monads

A monad is a pattern. The pattern is, sometimes you have an adjective which does not add much when you repeat it. For example there is not much added when you say "a *delayed* delayed x" or "zero or more (zero or more xs)" or "either a null or else either a null or else an x." Similarly for the IO monad, not much is added by "a program to compute a program to compute an x" that is not available in "a program to compute an x."

The pattern is that there is some canonical merging algorithm which merges:

> join: given an `<adjective> <adjective> x`, I will make you an `<adjective> x`.

We also add two other properties, the adjective should be *outputtish*,

> map: given an `x -> y` and an `<adjective> x`, I will make you an `<adjective> y`

and *universally embeddable*,

> pure: given an `x`, I will make you an `<adjective> x`.

Given these three things and a couple axioms you happen to have a common "monad" idea which you can develop One True Syntax for.

Now this metaprogramming idea obviously contains a monad. In JS we would write,

```ts
interface IO<x> {
  run: () => Promise<x>
}
function join<x>(pprog: IO<IO<x>>): IO<x> {
  return { run: () => pprog.run().then(prog => prog.run()) };
}
function map<x, y>(prog: IO<x>, fn: (in: x) => y): IO<y> {
  return { run: () => prog.run().then(x => fn(x)) }
}
function pure<x>(input: x): IO<x> {
  return { run: () => Promise.resolve(input) }
}
// with those you can also define,
function bind<x, y>(prog: IO<x>, fn: (in: x) => IO<y>): IO<y> {
  return join(map(prog, fn));
}
```

But the fact that a pattern exists does not mean it is useful! I am claiming that these functions turn out to be *all you need* to resolve the problem above. And it is not hard to see why: you can use `bind` to create a function scope inside of which the adjective doesn't exist, and manipulate your values there:

```ts
function ourGoal<x, y, z>(
  fnProg: IO<(inX: x, inY: y) => IO<z>>,
  xProg: IO<x>,
  yProg: IO<y>): IO<z> {
    return bind(fnProg, fn =>
      bind(xProg, x =>
        bind(yProg, y => fn(x, y))));
}
```

## How this answers your question

Notice that in the above we **choose** an order of operations by how we write the three `bind`s. We could have written those in some other order. But we needed all the parameters to run the final program.

This choice of how we sequence our operations is indeed *realized* in the function calls: **you are 100% right.** But the way that you are doing it, with *only* function composition, is flawed because it demotes the effects down to side-effects in order to get the types through.

Comment: I *really* don’t want to come off as negative or antagonistic, but I’m not sure how else to say this: I don’t like this answer much at all. It reads more like a rambling monad tutorial blog post than an attempt to answer OP’s fairly specific question, and even as a seasoned Haskeller, I don’t find it terribly readable. It seems to make the argument that monads are patterns, which is good, but the bulk of the answer is spent saying “here’s what a monad is; it’s a math thing; it has some operations and laws” then saying “and lo, the IO monad”, which doesn’t seem very compelling at all.

Comment: @AlexisKing Thanks for the feedback; it is not received as negative or antagonistic. It is indeed more rambling than I'd have normally done; that's partly because it was composed in a rush, and partly because I really think that people don't grok the IO monad until they realize that they're doing metaprogramming.